# Concatenate arbitrary fields using xml in Oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, concatenation

I'm using an Oracle 10gR2 here.

I want to be able to make a `select * from TABLE` and get the output in a single line with all the columns concatenated by a separator.

According to what I found, XML processing seems to be the best way to do that. So I have this query:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from MY_TABLE') from dual;
```

Which will return a XML code. What I need now is to process that XML into final records. An example might help:

The usual query being:

```
select * form MY_TABLE
```

would return:

```
Col1   | Col2   | Col3
a      | b      | c
z      | x      | y
```

And now I want to do a query like

```
select somesxmlprocessing(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from MY_TABLE'), ',') as rows
from dual
```

That the result would now be:

```
rows
a,b,c
z,x,y
```

The trick is I can't previously know which columns does the table has. i.e. it will always be a `select * from` regardless how many fields has a table.

p.s.:
I have found a solution using aggregation functions over the data in `all_tab_columns` which kind of works. The annoying thing is that it is executed in two steps: first generate a select and then execute it. works, but I'd still like to know the one shot xml way..

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean, I don't really understand the last paragraph.

Comment: @MatthewWatson sure do! there you have it. Let me know if I miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any in build functions which would let you do this ( sounds like you are actually wanting to export the table as a CSV? , in which case, there is various tools for doing that ). You would need to write a function to do what you want, which shouldn't be too difficult. Probably worth looking through this [ask tom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:88212348059) to see if it helps you out.

Comment: Yeah, it's similar but not exactly an export I'm doing. It wont be dumped straight into a file.i.e. I have to deal a little with the string before. The idea of XML I took from this ask Tom: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:56974528113170

Also, I had used xml functions to do string aggregations before and they worked fine (from here: http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/one_row.html)